# How can we convert list with key value pair into dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
l1=[{"key1":["value1"]},{"key2":["value2"]},{"key3":["value3"]}]
```

convert and swap key to value and value to key...

the desired output should be:

```
d1={"value1":"key1","value2":"key2","value3":"key3"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [dictionary comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/):

```
d1 = {v[0]:k for d in l1 for k,v in d.items()}
```

output: `{'value1': 'key1', 'value2': 'key2', 'value3': 'key3'}`

*Note that, as dictionary keys are **unique**, this cannot handle a case were you would have several times the same value. This would only consider the **last** occurrence.*

Answer (score 1):

Since each sub-dict contains exactly one key-value pair, you can unpack the dict items according to the fixed structure and reconstruct the key-value pairs with a dict comprehension:

```
{v: k for [(k, [v])] in map(dict.items, l1)}
```